# Nested controllers that don't select in a select tag dropdown to hide another input element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have nested controllers and I'm using John Papa's style guide, so they are controller as. One controls the entire form for client validation and submit. The other controls a section of the HTML view that deals with location and is supposed to hide the STATE input for small COUNTRYs that don't have states, so no input should occur.

COUNTRY is selected in a select tag. The dropdown is a JSON translation object from a factory and the English selection works. If certain countries are selected, the STATE input should hide / disappear. The first problem is that does not happen. I presume the user click on a country in the dropdown is outside $digest and have $timeout() to insert it, but it still doesn't work. I'm not using ng-click because 2 clicks occur - 1 to open the select, and another to make the selection. The second and related problem is that countrySelected is undefined in SelectCountryController, and I can't figure out why. If I hard code a country, it all works on page load, but it has never worked with a user click in the select dropdown.

HTML

```
<div name = "postApartment4Rent" data-ng-controller = "InputFormController as cntrl">
  <form id = "residenceInput" name = "residenceInput" data-ng-submit="cntrl.submit()" >
        <div id="countryAndState" data-ng-controller="SelectCountryController as vm">
        <div class="boldHeading">
            <p>TEST Language: {{ vm.langKey }} </p> 
            <p translate>COUNTRY</p>
            <select data-ng-model="vm.countrySelected"
                data-ng-init="vm.countrySelected = vm.countrySelected || vm.countries[0].code"
                data-ng-options="country.code as country.text group by country.continent for country in vm.countries" >
            </select>
        <p>TEST selected item is : {{vm.countrySelected}}</p>
        </div>

        <div id="stateProvince">
            <div id="stateDiv" data-ng-hide="vm.hideState">
                <p class="boldHeading" translate>STATE</p>
                <input type="text" id="state" name="state" data-ng-model="cntrl.input.state" size="50" maxlength="50" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Angular/Javascript for the interior SelectCountryController

```
(function() { 'use strict';
  angular.module( 'residenceApp' ).controller( 'SelectCountryController', SelectCountryController ); //end of controller module
  SelectCountryController.$inject = [ '$translate', 'selectCountryTranslateFactory', '$timeout' ];


function SelectCountryController( $translate, selectCountryTranslateFactory, $timeout ) {
  var vm = this;        
  vm.langKey = {};
  vm.hideState = false;
  vm.countries = countries();
  vm.hideState = hideStateSelector();
function countries() {
  vm.langKey = $translate.use(); //use() as a getter
  return selectCountryTranslateFactory.withLangChoice( vm.langKey );
}
function hideStateSelector() {
  var countriesWithNoStates =[ "AI", "AG", "AW", "BS", "BB", "BM" ];
  if( countriesWithNoStates.indexOf( vm.countrySelected ) > -1 ) {
            $timeout(function() {
                vm.hideState = true;
                angular.element('stateDiv').trigger('click');
                return vm.hideState;
            }, 10); //end of $timeout
        }
  } //end of hideStateSelector function
} //end of controller function
})();
```

If it makes any difference, all this is in a partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Laird and I have come up with the solution, here is the implementation for using 'this' and $scope for updating the view.

```
(function(angular) { 
  'use strict';
  angular.module( 'residenceApp' ).controller( 'SelectCountryController', SelectCountryController ); //end of controller module
  SelectCountryController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$translate', '$timeout', 'selectCountryTranslateFactory'];


  function SelectCountryController($scope, $translate, $timeout, selectCountryTranslateFactory) {
    var vm = this;        
    vm.langKey = {};
    vm.hideState = false;
    vm.countries = countries();
    $scope.countrySelected = '';
    function countries() {
      vm.langKey = $translate.use(); //use() as a getter
      return selectCountryTranslateFactory.withLangChoice( vm.langKey );
    }
    function hideStateSelector(countrySelected) {
      var countriesWithNoStates =[ "AI", "AG", "AW", "BS", "BB", "BM" ];
      if( countriesWithNoStates.indexOf( countrySelected ) !== -1 ) {
        $timeout(function() { 
          vm.hideState = true; 
        }, 0 );
      } else {
        vm.hideState = false;
      }
    } //end of hideStateSelector function
    $scope.$watch('vm.countrySelected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      hideStateSelector(countrySelected);
    });
  }
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm getting "Error: vm.$watch is not a function" and no Angularjs executes, so I get raw HTML instead of the translation values, etc.  Also, what is window.angular in the last line of your response. I put it in, but I've never seen it before.

Comment: With a check to John Papa's style guide, the watch has to have $scope, so I used $scope.$watch( "countrySelected", function() { hideStateSelector() }); The page now loads with translations and the select tag has its dropdown, but when a selection is made, nothing happens.

Comment: countrySelected now has defined values, but I'm getting "Error: [$rootScope:inprog]"  Are you sure $watch is the way to go?

Comment: I got rid of the $rootscope error with this instruction:  $scope.$watch( "countrySelected", function( newVal, oldVal ) { hideStateSelector() });  But hide still does not happen, e.g., when the country "AI" is selected.  Also, I removed window.angular and it seemed to have no change on behavior. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: What you see is the proper way to inject angular into singleton javascript functions. Not many people do it the right way :D, you're not going to see a difference but could prevent some random errors from occurring if angular doesn't load for some reason. I wasn't sure if you could register scope via 'this', but you are on the right track with injecting $scope as that is the most common method of two-way binding.

Comment: I updated the solution, try that and see how it works with using $scope and passing back the new value from the watcher.

Comment: Any update on this? I posted something new to try in the **NEW** section.

Comment: Back now after being gone for the weekend. vm.$watch() generates the error Error: vm.$watch is not a function, but $scope.$watch() makes no errors. countrySelected generates not defined, but vm.countrySelected works. The function definition for hideStateSelector() (your checkState) inherits variables from above so an arguement in hideStateSelector() generates errors. When I make those changes, I get no Console errors and pages load correctly, but State input does not hide when I click on the AI country (Anguilla) in the select dropdown.

Comment: Just to add clarity, the function looks like: function hideStateSelector() {var countriesWithNoStates =[ "AI", "AG", etc]; if( countriesWithNoStates.indexOf( vm.countrySelected ) !== -1 ) { vm.hideState = true;}}

Comment: I put alerts inside hideStateSelector() and neither fires when a user selection is made from the dropdown. Seems like the problem is in $watch()

Comment: 90% home. $watch has to watch vm.countrySelected.  hideStateSelector function now works, but I'm getting an error - Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest  What's the last step?

Comment: $timeout() is required - see the Google error doc link above. Here's the code. Put it in your answer. I'll give a green check mark. I could not have done it without your re-direction and better start.    $scope.$watch( "vm.countrySelected", function( newVal, oldVal ) { hideStateSelector(vm.countrySelected) });  and the function  function hideStateSelector() { var countriesWithNoStates =[ "AI", "AG", etc ];  if( countriesWithNoStates.indexOf( vm.countrySelected ) !== -1 ) { $timeout( function() { vm.hideState = true; }, 0 ); } else { vm.hideState = false; } } //end of hideStateSelector function

Comment: Glad I could help, I've updated the answer to show the solution, cheers!